# Nvidia GeForce GTX 460 Heat Security

Tags: graphics-card, temperature, nvidia-geforce

I am running some pretty heavy calculations (Running Bitcoin hash-mining) on my Nvidia GeForce GTX 460, and, needless to say, I´m quite paranoid whenever the heat reaches 50 degrees celcius (Which it *always* does).

So, if I were to leave it on over the night, is there any built-in security-measures (Like automatic restarts whenever heat´s above X degrees)?

If not, what happens if the heat go over, say 80 degrees? Would it just keep working ´til it burns to death?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually video card can take temperatures of 100C (in your specific case, [104C](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-460-us.html)), so 50C is quite fine.

As for safeties, all recent NVIDIA cards have thermal shutdown features, so system should power down before card is damaged. As far as I've seen, the shutdown temperature should be 125C, but I don't have exact source for 400 series cards. It could be lower on them.

Comment: Yeah, I knew the max-temperature. The problem in my particular case was that the temperature was increasing rapidly, so every so often I had to shut the process down for it to cool down. If I had not, it would have spiked up to well beyond 104 degrees. Anyhow, thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Marcus Hansson Did you ever reach 104 degrees? On my computer, the heat graph looks like positive side of e^(-1/x). It heats up rapidly and then starts slowing down. At one point the temperature stabilizes. Just to be sure, use GPU-Z to get some temperature data on the card and see what happens after several hours of running.

Comment: I had it running this night constantly at 2 (On a scale from 1-32) this night, it never really reached beyond 74 degrees. Although this isn´t optimal, it works. And yes, you are right, it spiked up but settled after a while (About 65 degrees). I expect it to settle appropriately at higher levels of work.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Nvidia GPUs are not the best choice for mining bitcoin. If you are trying to mine with Nvidia, your power costs will be a lot higher then your return of bitcoins. If you are serious about mining bitcoins, invest in a couple high end ATI Cards and you can see a positive return on your investment. I know this doesn't answer your question but it is advice you can use a lot more in the long run.